# Is TLS 1.2 supported for Workflow Manager on SharePoint 2013 on prem?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, workflow-manager, service-bus, windows-server-2012

I'm am trying to determine if we can disable `TLS 1.0`. Doing so currently causes the service bus to get stuck on starting and cause issue with workflows. I see in WebPI there is an update to service bus with `TLS 1.2` support, but I am not sure that it applies to our environment.

The article says as part of the upgrade process to install `Service Fabric 5.1` through WebPI. This update does not appear in the list. Only the SDK downloads show up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You need be on WFM 1.0 cu 5 level, as In CU 5 Adds support for the TLS protocol versions 1.1 and 1.2.

[Description of the Cumulative Update 5 for Workflow Manager 1.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055730/description-of-the-cumulative-update-5-for-workflow-manager-1-0)

TLS 1.2 support for Workflow Manager and Office Online Server when communicating with a SharePoint Server 2016 farm that has forced TLS 1.2 communications must be manually enabled when Office Online Server or Workflow Manager are installed on Windows Server 2012 R2. There are two requirements to enable TLS 1.2 support. First, make sure Update for Disabling RC4 in .NET TLS is installed. Second, add the SchUseStrongCrypto value.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

Import the key into each OOS/WFM server, then restart.

[TLS 1.2 Support for Workflow Manager and Office Online Server](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2016/04/tls-1-2-support-workflow-manager-office-online-server/)

Comment: I have done these step already. I'm on SharePoint 2013 on prem. We also do not have a separate workflow server. Attempting to disable TLS 1.0 causes the service bus to stop working.

Comment: did you apply the cu 5 for workflow manager?

Comment: Yes I did. The only thing I can think of is to install the `Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1 with TLS 1.2 Support`. I have tried, but the articles says that I need `Service Fabric 5.1` from WebPI. This update never shows up for me though.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49496, did you apply the service bus 1.1 updates?

Comment: Yes it's installed. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4077554/add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-on-service-bus-for-windows-server is the update I've been trying to install to see if that fixes the issue, but not had any success.

Comment: @MickB, were you successfully installed the CU for workflow manager to enable TLS 1.2? if so, please share the required links.